# Is there a way to save an array within an array using swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

Is it possible to save an array of names within an array? For example, Lets say we have 2 car companies, Toyota and Honda. And lets say we want to create an array within the car company array of the cars they make. For example...

```
var ArrayWithinArray = ["Toyota, "SIENNA", "CAMRY"", "Honda, "Odyssey", "Civic""]
```

How would i do this using swift?

Comment: An Array is an object.  An Array is an object which contains pointers to other objects.  Think about it.

Comment: What do you mean? How can i a list of data within a list?

Comment: I believe Dictionary [String : AnyObject] will be best here - company as a key and array of cars as value.

Comment: @HotLicks <pedantry>In Swift, an array is a value which contains other values.</pedantry> Those values may or may not be references (pointers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such situation, you can create an dictionary of arrays like this:

```
var listData = [
"Toyota": ["SIENNA", "CAMRY"],
"Honda": ["Odyssey", "Civic"]
]
```

To access a particular model, ("SIENNA" here)

```
let model = listData["Toyota"]?.first ?? "Car not found"
```

`model` will contain `SIENNA`

And if you want to iterate over all models

```
for model in listData["Toyota"] ?? [] {
    println(model)
}
```

Comment: That sure looks more like a dictionary of arrays to me.

Comment: How would i get the sienna value to print? println(self.listData[?])

Comment: I get an error that says. "Expression resolves to an unused l-value"

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus added your comment as answer, thanks for it

Comment: Best not to use `!` like that.  `println(listData["Toyota"]?.first ?? "Car not found")`

Comment: To add another model `listData["Toyota"]?.append("Prius")`.  To add a whole new line of cars: `listData["Ford"] = ["Taurus", "F-150"]`.